# Debugging in Netbeans C++ doesn't start - OSX Yosemite -

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, netbeans, gdb

I'm having trouble to make a debugging for C ++ osx Yosemite (I tried different IDE and each of them gives a problem), I read on google install gdb with brew ... but nothing.
with NetBeans, launch debugging, and in the console output I get the shell gdb:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3 +: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
--- Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit ---
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
--- Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit ---
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb)
```

I want to debug driven by using netbeans gui, step into, step over etc ....
This is a configuration of netbeans:

[image: Configuration Debug Netbeans]

And I also follwed this steps to install gdb:

http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

Thanks

---

EDIT

debugging configuration on netbeans:

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your debugging options tab

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. That's what I did to fix it (under Yosemite):

1. Install `brew`: http://brew.sh
2. Update `brew`. If you already have installed `brew`, check for updates. In the terminal:

```
$ brew update
```

This step turned out to be decisive for me as, before updating, `brew` did not find any `gdb` package:

```
$ brew install gdb # Error: No available formula for gdb
```

And after that:

```
$ brew update
$ brew search | grep gdb # cgdb gdb gdbm pgdbf
```

3. Install gdb:

```
$ brew install gdb
```

4. Codesign the binary following these instructions (similar to the ones James pointed): http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin I copy them here for the sake of completeness and to add some comments:

> **Creating a certificate**
>
> - Start Keychain Access application (`/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app`)
> - Open menu `/Keychain Access/Certificate Assistant/Create a Certificate...`
> - Choose a name (`gdb-cert` in the example), set `Identity Type` to `Self Signed Root`, set `Certificate Type` to `Code Signing` and select the `Let me override defaults`. Click several times on `Continue` until you get to the `Specify a Location For The Certificate` screen, then set `Keychain` to `System`.
> - If you can't store the certificate in the `System` keychain, create it in the `login` keychain, then exported it. You can then imported it into the `System` keychain.
> - Finally, using the contextual menu for the certificate, select `Get Info`, open the `Trust` item, and set `Code Signing` to `Always Trust`.
> - You must quit Keychain Access application in order to use the certificate and restart `taskgated` service by killing the current running taskgated process (comment: for example with `sudo pkill taskgated` or restarting).

And then

> **Giving gdb permission to control other processes**
>
> If the certificate is known as `gdb-cert`, just use:
>
> ```
> $ codesign -s gdb-cert gdb
> ```
>
> Comment: if `gdb` is not found, then add the path where it was installed. In my case:
>
> ```
> $ codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.10/bin/gdb
> ```

5. Use either `gdb` or the path where gdb was installed (for example, `/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.10/bin/gdb`) in the menu `/Netbeans/Preferences/C/C++/Build Tools` field `Debugger Command field`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired Codesigning the gdb executable?

> The Darwin Kernel requires the debugger to have special permissions
>   before it is allowed to control other processes. These permissions are
>   granted by codesigning the GDB executable. Without these permissions,
>   the debugger will report error messages such as:
>
> ```
> Starting program: /x/y/foo
> Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 28885: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
>  (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
> ```
>
> Codesigning requires a certificate. The following procedure explains how to create one:
>
> - Start the Keychain Access application (in /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app)
> - Select the Keychain
>     Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Create a Certificate... menu
> - Then:
>
>   - Choose a name for the new certificate (this procedure will use
>       "gdb-cert" as an example)
>   - Set "Identity Type" to "Self Signed Root"
>   - Set "Certificate Type" to "Code Signing"
>   - Activate the "Let me override defaults" option
> - Click several times on "Continue" until the "Specify
>     a Location For The Certificate" screen appears, then set "Keychain" to "System"
> - Click on "Continue" until the certificate is created
> - Finally, in the view, double-click on the new certificate, and set "When using
>     this certificate" to "Always Trust"
> - Exit the Keychain Access application and restart the computer (this is unfortunately required)
>
> Once a certificate has been created, the debugger can be codesigned as
>   follow. In a Terminal, run the following command...
>
> ```
> codesign -f -s  "gdb-cert"  <gnat_install_prefix>/bin/gdb
> ```
>
> ... where "gdb-cert" should be replaced by the actual certificate name
>   chosen above, and  should be replaced by the
>   location where you installed GNAT.

*Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html*